# Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this logic?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was solving a question on Hackerrank. The following is the question (in brief):

*There exist n robbers trying to rob a bank. They can stay there for atmost G minutes. Only two robbers can enter a vault at a time.*

`a[]={a_1,a_2,...,a_n}` *is a user specified array such that* `a_i` *is the time the* `i_th` *robber wishes to stay in the vault.*

*A heist is successful if all the robbers get their wish.*

*Given* `n,G, a[];` *the output must be "success" or "failure".*

My logic was as follows:
sort(a) in descending order
 define slot1 and slot2 for 1st and 2nd person in vault respectively
 slot1=slot2=G
 fill in slot1 and slot2 from the sorted a, such that whenever a robber is finished in the slot, the next one takes his place
If all robbers can be accommodated, then success, else failure.

Comment: Why is there a problem with your logic?

Comment: If you take the scenario with robbers `{2, 2, 2, 3, 3}`, your logic would fail, since you want to have `2-2-2` and `3-3` for your groups

Comment: Can a robber enter the vault twice?

Comment: This is the knapsack problem, isn't it? Which is NP-complete. This suggests that you have to try out all possible subsets of `a[]`. How big can `n` be?

Comment: They can't enter twice.
@JonTheMon: Got it. Thanks !

Comment: Did any of the answers, well, answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As JonTheMon noted above, your approach would fail when `G = 6` and `a = {2, 2, 2, 3, 3}`.

Anyway, your idea is wrong and you would not be able to solve the problem in such a way. Here is a hint:

> This is a classical DP problem.

*old post with wrong test case*:

Let `G = 4` and `a[] = {1, 2, 2, 3}`.

As far as I understood your approach, you will first accommodate robbers a_1 and a_2. After a_1 finished, you will introduce a_3 on his place. However, this leaves a_4 without enough time in a vault - only 2 minutes where he wanted to be inside at least 3.

Comment: *sort(a) in descending order*

Comment: @AntonSavin You're right. I can correct it, but it seems JonTheMon already wrote the intuition behind the falling test case.

Comment: @AntonSavin *descending order* yes, but the logic of the counterexample holds nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I would try having a double pass. First, add up all the time the robbers would want, then halve and round up. That's your ideal time. (at this point, check if one of your robbers is at/over this amount; if so, then that's your limit.) Then, try to fit robbers into that time frame. If you can fit them evenly, you're good. Otherwise, increase the time and try again.